# Laravel read multiple image path from Table

Tags: laravel

I'm having a hard time to read multiple file paths from my product tables in laravel.

I'm using Voyager as my admin interface, I have a multiple file upload that saves my path image in a field, when i query the table i get these result:

[image: Example]

how do i read the photo field?

Already tried:
**json_decode($product->photo,true)** and it says "htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given"

with **@foreach ($product->photo as $img)** it gives me "Invalid argument supplied for foreach() "

Comment: can you show in your model class.look like you have added $casts for that field as array

Comment: @JohnLobo tkz for your comment, already solve using $casts in the model as you said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**photo** column must be defined as **JSON** in its migrations file.

```
$table->json('photo');
```

And cast it to array in Product Model class:

```
protected $casts = [
   "photo" => "array"
];
```

Now you will access photo as array and do what you want.

Comment: Tkz a lot... it worked like a charm... ;)